# Get unauthorize when trying to exchange code for a token using OpenIddict

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openiddict

I am using OpenIddict authorization code flow with windows authentication; looked at this [example](https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-iv-authorization-code-flow-3eh8) everything seems to correct except I cannot exchange the code for a token, it's not even hitting the /token endpoint for some reason (I am getting 401 - Unauthorized).  It's getting the code without any issue. Am I missing anything ?

I am using Net8

```
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
               .UseDbContext<DbContext>();
    }).AddServer(options =>
    {

        options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
           .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("authorize")
                .SetTokenEndpointUris("token");

        options.AddEncryptionKey(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Convert.FromBase64String("DRjd/GnduI3Efzen9V9BvbNUfc/VKgXltV7Kbk9sMkY=")));

        options.AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

        options.UseAspNetCore()
                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough();
    })

     .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Adding the App

```
await using (var scope = app.Services.CreateAsyncScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContext>();
    await context.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
    var manager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOpenIddictApplicationManager>();
    await manager.CreateAsync(new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
    {
        ClientId = "console_app",
        RedirectUris =
                {
                    new Uri("https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback")
                },
        Permissions =
                {
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Authorization,
                    Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                    Permissions.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode,
                    Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code,
                    Permissions.ResponseTypes.Token
                }
    });
}
```

Endpoints

```
app.MapGet("/authorize", (HttpContext context, IOpenIddictScopeManager manager) =>
{
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
       authenticationType: TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType,
       nameType: Claims.Name,
       roleType: Claims.Role);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(Claims.Subject, context!.User!.Identity!.Name!.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    identity.SetDestinations(claim => [Destinations.AccessToken]);

    return Results.SignIn(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), properties: null, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}).RequireAuthorization();

app.MapPost("/token", (HttpContext context, IOpenIddictScopeManager manager) =>
{
    return Results.Ok("");
}));

app.Run();
```

Comment: According to the article the Authorize method doesn't RequireAuthorization method, it checked the user firstly by using cookie authentication firstly inside the previous article ` HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`. So if you want to achieve the same thing, you need implement the cookie authentication firstly as the article said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigating, the issue was fixed by allowing Windows authentication and anonymous. the token segment usea basic authentication.